# Kivy Desktop App with different user types

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making a Contract Management desktop application with python and kivy. The thing is, it has three types of users (Visitor,Editor and Admin) Each type of user has a different interface than the other.(The editor can do what the visitor can + other widgets and the admin inherits the Editor's widgets + other widgets) I'm really lost on how I can make the authentification system to load the right widgets for the right user. do I need to make three different user interfaces? or can I make a function that creates the user interface in function of the role?

Comment: Thats hard to answer generally. One of the simplest ways would be to add a check of the user type and depending actions to the screen/layout like for example `if user_type == 'admin':` and then add depending widgets within the if clause. Or you could set a security level like `if user_level >= 1:` then add the general options of visitors and then another `if user_level >=  2:` do the stuff for the editor and so on. These are just really simple approaches.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've managed to find a solution with a similar approach as you've proposed. I've made a method in the login screen app which get the user role during signing in and another method that adds widgets in function of the role and it works really fine.